# Bash/sed: delete everything from text file except match(es)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text file which I need to extract a match from in a bash script. There might be more than one match and everything else is supposed to be discarded.

Sample snippet of `input.txt` file content:

```
PART TWO OF TWO PARTS-
E RESNO 56/20 56/30 54/40 52/50 TUDEP
EAST LVLS NIL
WEST LVLS 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390
EUR RTS WEST NIL
NAR NIL-
REMARKS.
1.TMI IS 142 AND OPERATORS ARE REMINDED TO INCLUDE THE
TMI NUMBER AS PART OF THE OCEANIC CLEARANCE READ BACK.
2.ADS-C AND CPDLC MANDATED OTS ARE AS FOLLOWS
TRACK A 350 360 370 380 390
TRACK B 350 360 370 380 390
```

I try to match for `142` from the line

```
1.TMI IS 142 AND OPERATORS ARE REMINDED TO INCLUDE THE
```

The match is always a number (one to three digits, may have leading zeroes) and always preceded by `TMI IS`.

My experiments so far led to nothing: I tried `.*TMI IS ([0-9]+).*` with the following `sed` command in my bash script

```
sed -n 's/.*TMI IS \([0-9]+\).*/\1/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

but only got an empty `output.txt`.

My script runs in `GNU Bash-4.2`. Where do I make my mistake? I ran out of ideas so your input is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Why not use grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two moments about your ***sed*** approach to make it work:

- `+` quantifier should be escaped in *sed* basic regular expressions
- to print matched pattern use `p` subcommand:

---

```
sed -n 's/.*TMI IS \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/gp' input.txt
142
```

---

To get only the first match for your current *format* use:

```
sed -n 's/^\S\+TMI IS \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/gp' input.txt
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that `\+` is a GNU sed extension.  `[0-9][0-9]*` or `[0-9]\{1,\}` can be used instead.

Comment: How about a line with 2 matches `TMI IS 321 TMI IS 123` ? Your `g` suggets a global action, but the first `.*` is greedy and you only get the second match.

Comment: To print the matched pattern you can also simply remove the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
$ grep -oP 'TMI IS \K([0-9]*)' input.txt
142
```

Comment: This is using a GNU extension though, so won't work if you don't have GNU grep

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using `perl` as an alternative to the above:

```
$ perl -nle 'print $1 if /TMI IS (\d+)/;' < input.txt
142
```